# How to create index on columns with one of them having NULL value?

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

In Oracle, below is the `TableA` schema:

```
 PK(id)
 col_2 VARCHAR2(2)
 col_3 VARCHAR(16)
 col_4 VARCHAR(3)
 col_5 NUMBER
```

---

```
 CREATE INDEX idx_tableA ON TableA (col_2, col_3, col_4);
```

creates an index on `TableA` but...

scenario is, any record in `TableA` will either have `col_3` as NULL or `col_4` as NULL but not both columns as NULL

Does index `idx_tableA` work for `col_2`, `col_3` & `col_4`? without having record no present issue....

Answer (score 1):

The drawback of that is that there will be a lot of records having the same first dimension for the index with your current implementation. You can use COALESCE for your indexing like

```
CREATE INDEX idx_tableA_2 ON TableA (COALESCE(col_2, col_3), col_4);
```

and then use `COALESCE(col_2, col_3)` in your searches.

Alternatively, you could create an index for (col_2, col_4) and (col_3, col_4).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle will store your row in a b-tree index **as long as at least *one* of the indexed columns is not null**. So yes, you can index the columns you described as desired. For performance of queries using it, though, you have several options:

1. Push your nullable columns to the end of the indexed column list. Apply an equality predicate to the leading column(s) and then look for NULLs in the nullables with the predicate `IS NULL`. For example:

   ```
    SELECT *
      FROM tableA
     WHERE col_2 = 12345
       AND col_3 IS NULL
   ```
2. If you don't use a predicate on a nullable column and wish only to look for a NULL value, in addition to placing that column on the left edge of the index, you also have to tell your query that the other indexed column is not null so that it knows it will find it in the index, otherwise it won't even consider using the index because of the possibility that all the indexed columns are NULL and hence the row(s) of interest wouldn't be found at all in the index. For example:

   ```
    CREATE INDEX idx_tableA ON TableA (col_3, col_4);

    SELECT *
      FROM tableA
     WHERE col_3 IS NULL
       AND col_4 IS NOT NULL -- dummy just to force index use
   ```

However it is very rare that you would want to seek on a NULL value like this, unless it was a very special row.

If you are seeking on either of two columns (and so using an `OR`) and the columns are high cardinality, then a function-based index using `NVL` or `COALESCE` might be a good idea. This enables it to seek (continue using a binary search algorithm) on these latter columns:

```
    CREATE INDEX idx_tableA ON TableA (col1, NVL(col_3,col_4));

    SELECT *
      FROM tableA
     WHERE col_2 = 12345
       AND NVL(col_3,col4) = 5678
```

If they are low-cardinality (few values), and you are also providing a non-null predicate, then don't bother. Oracle will see on the non-null predicate and then scan index leaf blocks (no longer using a binary search) testing the remainder of the indexed columns per your `OR` and it likely won't be noticeably slower than if it were seeking.

```
    CREATE INDEX idx_tableA ON TableA (col1,col_3,col_4);

    SELECT *
      FROM tableA
     WHERE col_2 = 12345
       AND (col_3 = 1 OR col4 = 1)
```